# Why doesn't dbcursor.count() accord with the times of hasNext-then-next iteration?

Tags: java, mongodb

A weird problem:
I print the dbcursor.count() , which yeilds a number the same as what I get from the mongo shell, using db.collectionName.count().

However,
when I do like this,

```
DBCursor cursor = myCollection.find(someQuery);
int count = cursor.count();
int cnt = 0;
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    cnt++;               
    DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) cursor.next();
}
```

After that, the count and cnt give conflict results:
the former is as what I expect,
while the later is far less than the former.

I then checked the mongodb DBCursor API doc.
http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html

And from the wording of count() and hasNext()

```
public int count()
    throws MongoException

Counts the number of elements in this cursor.  

Returns:
       the number of elements
```

and

```
public boolean hasNext()

Checks if there is another element.

Returns:
    if there is another element
```

It implies that count and cnt should be the same.
And just for the record, during the process the mongodb
has neither insertion nor deletion operation.(I tested on 
a mirror db just for testing)

Any idea?

Comment: So you are saying that `cursor.count()` gives you the correct result but when you iterate over the results you get less objects than expected?

Comment: And, you do or don't use a query for both? Is there an index involved?

Comment: @WiredPrairie. you do or don't use a query for both? - > No query. Is there an index involved? -> yep.

Comment: @larmbr It might be due to your index being corrupted. You could try to remove and recreate the index (on your mirror testing db).

Comment: Hello larmbr, did you try to recreate index as suggested? Regards, Moacy

Comment: @Moacy Barros I think it is cause by , as assylias comments, index corruption, and I have tried on another "healthy" mongodb, this problem dismisses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @assylias comments, it is likely due to an index corruption.